# Deleting named ranges from active cells in google sheets with a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, named-ranges

I am new to the google sheets environment and my limited knowledge of VBA does not help. I would like to be able to delete range names from a cell or multiple cells selected by the "curser" on google sheets.

I did manage code deleting all named ranges from a sheet but that is not what I want. Your assistance will be appreciated.

[Illustrate Active Cell and Named range circled in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JGiu.png)

I would like the script to delete the named range map_4bf9.... in live cell C17. Preferably I would like to be able to select say range C17:H18 and let the script delete the named ranges from all those cells which are next to each other.

To do it manually in google sheets you will go to Data/Named Ranges and then search for the range name from the listing to the right and then manually delete it.

[Google sheets select named ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKdfL.png)

[Search and manually delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZndy.png)

The script removing all named ranges on a sheet was as follows:

function delRange(){
var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getNamedRanges();
for(i=0;i<namedRanges.length;i++){
namedRanges[i].remove();
}
}

Comment: Do you mean to redefine a named range (all named ranges?) to exclude selected cells from it (them)?

Comment: How do you propose to run this script.  You could use the `onSelectionChange(e)` trigger but everytime you change the selected cell it will run and interfer with changing values in a valid named range.  My suggestion is run it from menu item or or a button. How does that sound?

Comment: no I want to delete named ranges from selected "active" cells .... the named ranges in cells not selected must remain. I will just run it as an "appscript" while redesigning a google project. the manual way is to go to Data/Named Ranges/Search for the named range and then delete it. Very long process.

Comment: You are not going to be able to do that.  You can not remove a cell somewhere within the bounds of a multiple cell named range.  Try it you can not create a named range of non-contiguous cells.  It has to be cell or a rectangular block of cells.

Comment: About `I did manage code deleting all named ranges from a sheet but that is not what i want.`, can you provide your current script?

Comment: Can you do it manually? Could you please to show the desired result somehow (a screenshot, or/and a description)? Because from your question it is not clear: either you want to delete some named range from the spreadsheet, or you want to 'clean' selected cells from any assigned range and keep all named ranges (with updated definitions probably) in the spreadsheet.

Comment: I've added more information which hopefully will assist.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite what you were asking for, but it comes close I believe.

Image of Original Data:

[image]

Image of Active Ranges

[image]

Image of range After Running Code:

[image]

```
function myFunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const remove = sh.getActiveRangeList();
  const rg = ss.getRangeByName('Array1');
  const row = rg.getRow();
  const col = rg.getColumn();
  let vs = rg.getValues();
  Logger.log('Before\n %s',JSON.stringify(vs).replace(/],/g,'],\n'));
  remove.getRanges().forEach(r => r.setValue(""));
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  vs = rg.getValues()
  Logger.log('After:\n %s',JSON.stringify(vs).replace(/],/g,'],\n'));
}

Execution log
9:01:23 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:01:23 AM  Info    Before
 [[17,20,26,0,10],
[10,31,22,24,4],
[19,31,16,1,29],
[3,5,17,22,8],
[15,0,30,11,30],
[7,5,23,10,3]]
9:01:23 AM  Info    After:
 [["",20,26,0,""],
[10,31,22,24,4],
[19,31,16,1,29],
[3,5,17,22,8],
[15,0,30,11,30],
["",5,23,10,""]]
9:01:25 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

I think this version is closer to what you might be looking for because it just changes the values of the active cells in the array without actually changing the values in the range.

```
function myFunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const remove = breakUpRangeList(ss,sh,sh.getActiveRangeList());
  const rg = ss.getRangeByName('Array1');
  const row = rg.getRow();
  const col = rg.getColumn();
  let vs = rg.getValues();
  let bs = vs.slice();
  Logger.log('Before\n %s',JSON.stringify(vs).replace(/],/g,'],\n'));
  remove.getRanges().forEach(r => bs[r.getRow()-row][r.getColumn()-col] = "")
  Logger.log('After:\n %s',JSON.stringify(bs).replace(/],/g,'],\n'));
  return bs;
}
```

And it requires this helper function which breaks rangeLists into separate single cell rangelists

```
function breakUpRangeList(ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0"), rgl) {
  let b = [];
  rgl.getRanges().forEach(rg => {
    rg.getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
      let row = rg.getRow() + i;
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        let col = rg.getColumn() + j;
        b.push(sh.getRange(row, col).getA1Notation())
      })
    })
  })
  b = [...new Set(b)];
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(b));
  return sh.getRangeList(b);
}
```

Using the same named range as before here is an image of the active range:

[image]

And here is the execution logs for this version:

```
Execution log
9:42:53 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:42:54 AM  Info    Before
 [[9,14,28,32,0],
[9,34,28,28,32],
[18,2,33,0,11],
[19,2,15,14,19],
[3,9,4,21,21],
[32,24,22,7,28]]
9:42:54 AM  Info    After:
 [["","",28,32,0],
["","",28,28,32],
["","",33,0,11],
[19,2,15,14,19],
[3,9,4,21,21],
[32,24,22,7,28]]
9:42:56 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Notice that no data in the original range or array has been changed

I got to thinking that this might be what you want. It's a rangeList of  the named range missing the active cells

```
function myFunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const remove = breakUpRangeList(ss, sh, sh.getActiveRangeList());
  const rg = ss.getRangeByName('Array1');
  const row = rg.getRow();
  const col = rg.getColumn();
  let vs = rg.getValues();
  let arr1 = vs.map((r, i) => r.map((c, j) => sh.getRange(i + row, j + col).getA1Notation())).flat();
  let arr2 = arr1.slice();
  remove.getRanges().forEach(r => { let idx = arr2.indexOf(r.getA1Notation()); if (~idx) { arr2.splice(idx, 1); } });
  Logger.log("arr2:\n %s",JSON.stringify(arr2));
  return sh.getRangeList(arr2);
}
```

> I think that's about it.  I can't think of any other workarounds

Comment: thanks for your efforts .... really appreciate. It looks like this code remove the content of the cell and not an underlying named range.

Comment: Nope, not the underlying named range. You don't alway get what you want but sometimes if your luckly you'll get what you need.